# How to test interaction effect with small sample size?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance, inference, interaction

Into my model x is categorical variable with 3 categories: 0,1 & 2, where 0 is reference category. However number of "0" categories are much larger than others (1,2) which increases the chance of a biased outcome.

```
X     N of rows
x=0    600
x=1    45
x=2    45
```

Let's say we have regression `y~x+z+xz`, where `xz` is the interaction term between x and z. My question is if you see any method/model to handle this issue and test the significance of the interaction term (except linear regression estimated by stratified bootstrap)?
R Code:

```
#Sample:
df <- data.frame (x  = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2),
                  y = c(10,11,10,10,12,17,16,20,19),
                  z = c(6,5,6,7,2,10,14,8,11))
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)
df$x <- relevel(df$x,ref = "0")


fit <- lm(y ~ x*z, data = df)

summary(fit)
```

Comment: What is the "issue" to which you refer?  Testing in ordinary least squares (which is what `lm` does) works no matter what the category counts are, provided each category appears at least once.  Thus, the output of `summary` has already performed the test of interaction.  What more would you be looking for?  BTW, please don't post additional versions of your question: if you need to modify it, just edit this post.

Comment: I want to avoid biased outcome

Comment: There is no bias in OLS estimates.

Comment: Anyway, I need another method/model to double-check my results

Comment: Could you explain what kind of checking you need?  Another method or model, if truly different, would produce different results, too.  Instead, usually results are checked through various diagnostic and *post hoc* plots to assess the credibility of the model assumptions and to help interpret its estimates.